# Does "ruin the experience" sound informal?

Tags: phrase-usage, formal-language, register

Does "ruin the experience" sound informal?

I'm writing an essay and I'm wondering if it's appropriate to use such a phrase.

Comment: An essay is meant to be a personal account.  But there isn't really enough detail to provide an answer here.  You should probably just use it and find out what your teacher thinks. It is usually better to try and fail than never to try at all.

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound informal. It may sound a bit trendy.

Comment: What do you mean by "trendy"?

Comment: “Trendy” is a trendy word that means “heavily used at the current time.” There is nothing wrong with using such words, but using them does (1) tend to  make your writing seem slightly routine in the current environment, and (2) may make your writing seem dated in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it sounds informal. But there are certainly classier expressions available to one.